# Google chrome, open link in second window new tab (is this easily possible)?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser, shortcuts, browser-tabs

I have two windows of chrome open, one window is on the left, a bookmark collection, one window on the right will be for viewing the bookmarks cleanly while the collection on the left remains open, then I can delete the crappy ones, arrange, whatever.

Is there a way to quickly send a link from hover or context menu (left window) to another tab in the second window (right window)? kind of like command+click on mac nicely opens a new tab while remaining on current tab in same window, but instead it will open new tab in the other window.

I looked at extensions, googled alot, couldn't find anything. I can open them then click the tab or tabs and move it but that's very slow and inefficient way to do it.

Maybe it's complex and would require code but hopefully not.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add [Open in specific window](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-in-specific-window/nkgphogbgnehgdfkpiknbdnjaamlbgmo/related?hl=en) which is an extension that:

> Adds a right-click menu that opens a link in a specified window

To open a link to a another opened window, right-click on the link, click on Open in specific window, then select the window that should host it.

> If you have multiple chrome windows open, this extension will add a right-click menu allowing you to choose which window to open the link in.
>
> The menu will automatically show the current window/tab title of the windows you can choose to open the link in. Optionally you can also name your open windows by clicking the "Open in specific window" icon in the upper right-hand corner.

**Caveats:** Reading the reviews, it seems that the although you might name your windows, the names are not retained after restarting the machine. Also <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> is not working.

Comment: I'll give it a try thanks, otherwise I would probably need applescript.

Comment: I really want this feature too, but don't feel great about "It can read and change all your data on all your websites."